# What's the difference between using and not using BTREE in MySQL 'CREATE TABLE' statement?

Tags: mysql, indexing, mysql-workbench, create-table, b-tree

I'm new to SQL, I want to create a table, I see an example:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `aaa`;
CREATE TABLE `aaa` (
`date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`id` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
...
`source` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
KEY `idx1` (`source`),
KEY `idx2` (`id`,`date`) USING BTREE,
KEY `idx3` (`date`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

I've been reading online about `USING BTREE` but still a bit confused, why `idx1` DOESN'T have it and `idx2`, `idx3` have `USING BTREE`? What's the difference and purpose? What's the advantage of using it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No difference, other than syntax.

- The default is `BTree`.
- If you say nothing, or even if you say `HASH`, it will be silently converted to `BTree`.

Essentially BTree a good, all-purpose, indexing mechanism.

- Finding a specific row ("point query") is very fast.  Eg: `WHERE x = 123`
- Scanning a "range" or rows is very efficient.  Eg: `WHERE x BETWEEN 333 AND 444`  (Contrast: Very slow for HASH.)

FULLTEXT and SPATIAL, if desired, require explicit specification.

You should really move from MyISAM to InnoDB.

See Wikipedia:  MyISAM uses B-Tree; InnoDB uses B+Tree.